# Error while running app.js in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am completely new to node and trying to work with webRTC application.
I have installed node,express and socket.io in my project, However when I try to run app.js I get error. I am unable to debug because I am not experienced enough to spot the error.

The following is the code in app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); // this tells socket.io to use our express server

    app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function(){
      app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);


console.log("Express server listening on port 3000");
```

When I write the command ***node app.js*** it shows the following error.
I have setup exprees in my project.

[image: This is the error shown in the terminal when I run ***app.js***]

The file structure inside webRTC directory is as follows

[image: This is the directory structure inside webRTC project]

Here is the link to webpage that accompanies step by step to setup node,npm express and socket.io inside a peoject . I have followed every step properly but the part where it says to run app.js after downloading socket.io it shows error.

[How to install node in ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-express-a-node-js-framework-and-set-up-socket-io-on-a-vps)

Here is the index.js code inside route folder where the error is occuring

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and here is the image which was previously not visible properly

[image]

Comment: Please include the error in your question as text, not an image..

Comment: The error is happening on line 5 of `/routes/index.js`, i would rather have seen `/routes/index.js` than `app.js`, if i had to see only one file.

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to do require('../app') but app.js isn't exporting anything for that to return.

Comment: @kevin, I am unable to understand what you are saying. Did you mean that I should run index.js and then app.js.

Comment: No.... what i'm saying is we have no idea how to fix your problem because it is happening elsewhere. All we can do is guess or vote to close until you give us more information.

Comment: Give us `/routes/index.js`, which is where the error occurs according to the  hard to read image you provided.

Comment: What version of express are you using? (check by opening package.json and reading dependencies section) Your usage of `express.Router` seems correct.

Comment: The express version in my project is 4.11.1